# Any limitations using C++ STL for iOS development?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, compiler-construction, cross-platform

My purpose is to reuse some C++ STL implementation for iOS development with static library.

As we know, iOS devices are based on ARM6/7 family,which is different with *86 family for some compiler options.

For mobile development, we prefer to reuse some C++ codes across different platforms,such as iOS, Android, and even for the PC back end.

So question here to know some issues or limitations for this purpose.

Thanks

---

C++ STL just refer some popular version,I do not want to cover all STL libs, I just want to know some popular issues for this case. Thanks for pointing any out.

Comment: When you say "some STL implementation", do you mean "any STL implementation" or "one specific STL implementation"? Because AFAIK the STL that ships with Xcode works perfectly with iDevices. As long as you don't do assembly code yourself I don't see what could not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main purpose of using standardized tools is to achieve portability. As long as you use the library as intended, without relying on behavior outside the standard, there should not be any issues moving it to *any* platform with a good C++ implementation.

The Standard Library implementation on iOS is the same as the one on Mac OS. There should be no difference.

ARM vs x86 should make no difference whatsoever. The part of the C++ Standard Library called the STL consists entirely of templates, hence "Standard *Template* Library." Templating over high-level data structures all but precludes assembly-language tricks.

Comment: The one caveat would be that you make sure to transition from STL collections to Cocoa collections gracefully when such transitions need to occur. As obtuse as that sounds, I've seen several examples of people trying to shoehorn STL into areas of Cocoa where it does not belong, creating more work than necessary and ending up in a lower quality product.

Answer (score 2):

No - when working for my previous employer, we used a whole protocol stack (with some STL) written in C++ for our desktop client to bootstrap development of our iPhone client.  Worked great.